# UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@16.0.0 Blueprint

Tags: reactjs, blueprintjs

Trying to install Blueprint: http://blueprintjs.com/docs/#blueprint.npm-installation

Have tried the manual install. Have tried installing the dependencies manually as  mentioned in step 2, but I keep getting:

```
UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@16.0.0
```

Which makes no sense. My package.json contains `"react": "^16.0.0"` and I installed react using create-react-app today, so what is going on here?

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "reactdemo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "1.0.14"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@blueprintjs/core": "^1.32.0",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
     "react-addons-css-transition-group": "^15.6.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-transition-group": "^1.2.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your package.json plz?

Comment: What are you using to install these dependencies? `npm` or `yarn`? What version of `node` and `npm` are you using? (Can you post the responses for: `npm -v` and `node -v`?)

Comment: npm: 4.0.5, node: 6.9.1

Comment: @MattSaunders In playing with it, it seems more like a bug... Contribute here: https://github.com/palantir/blueprint/issues/201#issuecomment-338252760

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To quote **@adidahiya** from BluePrint's own repo:

> If you're using **React 16**, we're currently in an awkward in-between state where we need `react-addons-css-transition` group for pre-16 support, ***hence the peer dep warnings***. *They should be safe to ignore for now.* Follow [#866](https://github.com/palantir/blueprint/issues/866) for more updates.

See [original issue ticket here](https://github.com/palantir/blueprint/issues/201#issuecomment-338252760), and the [issue to follow here](https://github.com/palantir/blueprint/issues/866).

Hope this helps.